# TensorFlow decode_csv shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I read in a `*.csv` file using `tf.data.TextLineDataset` and apply `map` on it:

```py
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(os.path.join(data_dir, subset, 'label.txt'))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda value: parse_record_fn(value, is_training),
                          num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
```

Parse function `parse_record_fn` looks like this:

```py
def parse_record(raw_record, is_training):
    default_record = ["./", -1]
    filename, label = tf.decode_csv([raw_record], default_record)
    # do something
    return image, label
```

But there raise an `ValueError` at `tf.decode_csv` in parse function:

`ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'DecodeCSV' (op: 'DecodeCSV') with input shapes: [1], [], [].`

My `*.csv` file example:

```py
/data/1.png, 5
/data/2.png, 7
```

**Question**:

1. Where goes wrong?
2. What does `shapes: [1], [], []` mean?

### Reproduce

This error can be reproduced in this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def parse_record(raw_record, is_training):
    default_record = ["./", -1]
    filename, label = tf.decode_csv([raw_record], default_record)

    # do something

    return image, label

with tf.Session() as sess:
    csv_path = './labels.txt'


    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(csv_path)

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda value: parse_record(value, True))


sess.run(dataset)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`tf.decode_csv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv), it says about the default records:

> record_defaults: A list of Tensor objects with specific types.
>   Acceptable types are float32, float64, int32, int64, string. One
>   tensor per column of the input record, with either a scalar default
>   value for that column or empty if the column is required.

I believe the error you are getting originates from how you define the tensor `default_record`. Your `default_record` certainly is a list of tensor objects (or objects convertible to tensors), but I think the error message is telling that they should be rank-1 tensors, not rank-0 tensors as in your case.

You can fix the issue by making the default records rank 1 tensors. See the following toy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

my_line = 'filename.png, 10'
default_record_1 = [['./'], [-1]] # do this!
default_record_2 = ['./', -1] # this is what you do now

decoded_1 = tf.decode_csv(my_line, default_record_1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    d = sess.run(decoded_1)
    print(d)

# This will cause an error
decoded_2 = tf.decode_csv(my_line, default_record_2)
```

The error produced on the last line is familiar:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'DecodeCSV_1' (op:
>   'DecodeCSV') with input shapes: [], [], [].

In the message, the input shapes, the three brackets `[]`, refer to the shapes of the input arguments `records`, `record_defaults`, and `field_delim` of `tf.decode_csv`. In your case the first of these shapes is `[1]` since you input `[raw_record]`. I agree that the message for this case is not very informative...